# How can I pick specific records in TensorFlow from a .tfrecords file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

My goal is to train a neural net for a fixed number of epochs or steps, I would like each step to use a batch of data of a specific size from a .tfrecords file.

Currently I am reading from the file using this loop:

```
i = 0
data = np.empty(shape=[x,y])

for serialized_example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(filename):

    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(serialized_example)

    Labels = example.features.feature['Labels'].byte_list.value
    # Some more features here

    data[i-1] = [Labels[0], # more features here]

    if i == 3:
        break
    i = i + 1

print data # do some stuff etc.
```

I am a bit of a Python noob, and I suspect that creating "i" outside the loop and breaking out when it reaches a certain value is just a hacky word-around.

Is there a way that I can read data from the file but specify "I would like the first 100 values in the byte_list that is contained within the Labels feature" and then subsequently "I would like the next 100 values".

To clarify, the thing that I am unfamiliar with is looping over a file in this manner, I am not really certain how to manipulate the loop.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try using `enumerate()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Impossible. TFRecords is a streaming reader and has no random access.

> A TFRecords file represents a sequence of (binary) strings. The format is not random access, so it is suitable for streaming large amounts of data but not suitable if fast sharding or other non-sequential access is desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if you could point me somewhere to learn about this kind of format more. Mostly I am just not sure what it might be useful for.

Comment: Is this only impossible from the API available? Maybe there’s a lower level solution?

Answer (score 2):

### Expanding on the comment by [Shan Carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327070/shan-carter) (although it's not an ideal solution for your question) for archival purposes.

If you'd like to use `enumerate()` to break out from a loop at a certain iteration, you could do the following:

```
n = 5 # Iteration you would like to stop at
data = np.empty(shape=[x,y])

for i, serialized_example in enumerate(tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(filename)):

    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(serialized_example)

    Labels = example.features.feature['Labels'].byte_list.value
    # Some more features here

    data[i-1] = [Labels[0], Labels[1]]# more features here

    if i == n:
       break

print(data)
```

### Addressing your use case for `.tfrecords`

> I would like each step to use a batch of data of a specific size from a .tfrecords file.

As mentioned by [TimZaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293689/timzaman), .tfrecords are not meant for arbitrary access of data. But seeing as you just need to continously pull batches from the `.tfrecords` file, you might be better off using the `tf.data` API to feed your model.

**Adapted from the the [tf.data guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_tfrecord_data):**

Constructing a `Dataset` from `.tfrecord` files

```py
filepath1 = '/path/to/file.tfrecord'
filepath2 = '/path/to/another_file.tfrecord
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = [filepath1, filepath2])
```

From here, if you're using the tf.keras API, you could pass `dataset` as an argument into `model.fit` like so:

```py
model.fit(x = dataset,
          batch_size = None,
          validation_data = some_other_dataset)
```

### Extra Stuff

Here's a [blog](https://planspace.org/20170323-tfrecords_for_humans/) which helps to explain `.tfrecord` files a little better than the tensorflow documentation.